# bxSlider not working properly with Knockoutjs

Tags: javascript, knockout.js, bxslider

I'm trying to get bxSlider to work properly after the data is loaded from db.

My knockoutjs code works as expected:

```js
BspApp.UspjesnaPrica = function (n) {
    var self = this;

    self.nid = n.id;
    self.naslov = n.naslov;
    self.datum = n.datum;
    self.prica = n.prica;
    self.detailUrl = '/vise/prica/' + n.id;
    self.imgUrl = n.imgPath;
}

BspApp.UspjesnePrice = function () {
    var self = this;
    self.price = ko.observableArray([]);
    self.a = "parent";

    self.ucitajSve = function () {

        $.get('dal/servis.php', { tip: 'price' }, function (price) {
            $.each(price, function (indx, prica) {
                self.price.push(new BspApp.UspjesnaPrica(prica));
            });
        }, 'json');
    }
}
```

And this is my html:

```
    <ul data-bind="foreach: price" id="priceSlider">
        <li>
            <a data-bind="attr: { href: detailUrl }">
                <img data-bind="attr: { src: imgUrl, title: naslov }" />
            </a>
        </li>
    </ul>
```

This is bxSlider and KO init code:

```
var uspjesneprice = new BspApp.UspjesnePrice();
uspjesneprice.ucitajSve();
ko.applyBindings(uspjesneprice, document.getElementById('uspjesneprice'));

var priceSlider = $("#priceSlider").bxSlider({
    mode: 'horizontal',
    hideControlOnEnd: true,
    adaptiveHeight: true,
    captions: true
});
```

After my data is loaded bxSlider not displaying correctly.

Also, hard-coded html tags works without problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because you're probably initializing the `bxSlider` before the ajax-request to `dal/servis.php` has finished.

What if you move the `bxSlider` code inside the ajax-callback:

```
$.get('dal/servis.php', { tip: 'price' }, function (price) {
    $.each(price, function (indx, prica) {
        self.price.push(new BspApp.UspjesnaPrica(prica));
    });
    var priceSlider = $("#priceSlider").bxSlider({
        mode: 'horizontal',
        hideControlOnEnd: true,
        adaptiveHeight: true,
        captions: true
    });
}, 'json');
```

Comment: The ajax request is asynchronous, meaning it will continue to execute the code below it while the request is being executed. Once the request is complete, the callback (3th parameter of `$.get`) will be called after the request has finished.